# How to join three tables in Oracle where one of the table has null values in the foreign key column?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have to execute the following:

```
select items.segment1

from   items
      ,po_lines
      ,po_shipments

where  po_lines.item_id = items.item_id(+)   --po_lines has null in some item_id 
       po_shipments.ship_to = items.org_id;
```

But the outer join seem to be not working. The query should return 100 values while it is returning only 85. It is neglecting the 15 for which `po_lines.item_id` is `null`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `(+)` operator should be applied to the table that's allowed to have "missing" rows - you have it on the wrong side of the join.

```
select items.segment1

from   items
      ,po_lines
      ,po_shipments

where  po_lines.item_id (+) = items.item_id   --po_lines has null in some item_id 
       po_shipments.ship_to = items.org_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Wikipedia JOIN (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29):

> ANSI-standard SQL specifies five types of JOIN: INNER, LEFT OUTER,
>   RIGHT OUTER, FULL OUTER and CROSS

You can use `left join` in this way:

```
select items.segment1
from   
   items
left outer join 
   po_lines on po_lines.item_id = items.item_i
inner join 
   po_shipments on  po_shipments.ship_to = items.org_id;
```

Your [oracle (*) syntax is deprecated](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm):

> Starting with Oracle9i, the confusing outer join syntax using the
>   ‘(+)’ notation has been superseded by ISO 99 outer join syntax.

Comment: Thnx.I will try that when I get to my lab tomorrow.